# Why do the html table rows appear in reverse order?

Tags: html, html-table, rows

Here is my code:

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">

<tr align="center">
    <td align="left" width="180">
        <a href="http://www.blabllablbalbla.com/"> <img border="0" alt="bablablabla"
        height="" src="/include/img/logo-beta.png"></img> </a>
    </td>
    <td align="right"><a href="http://support.blablalblbalabl.com">Help Center</a> | <a 
        href="/auth/login">Sign In</a>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    whyyyyyyyy does this appear on top???!
</tr>

</table>
```

and here is my js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/PQZTL/1/

I want the text to be below the broken image.

Can somebody explain this to me?

Comment: You can't put content directly inside a `<tr>`, you need to have a `<td>` inside. Also, you are using some inlined parameters in your elements that have been replace by CSS equivalents. Take a good read at www.w3schools.com on both HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 6):

The advice given, adding `<td>` tag(s), solves the practical problem, but as to the “why” question, the answer is that when browsers parse a table and find any content outside the correct syntax, they just collect it and place it *before* the table.

So “whyyyyyyyy does this appear on top???!” isn’t really treated as a row placed before the other row but as garbage outside rows and dumped ahead of the table. You can see this e.g. by using a style sheet rule like `table { border: solid red }`; the text then appears outside the border.

This browser behavior is described in the HTML5 draft as “foster parenting”, in section [Unexpected markup in tables](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-end.html#unexpected-markup-in-tables). (The heading is somewhat misleading, since browsers are really prepared to handling the situation in a specific way; so it’s really about handling *incorrect* markup in tables.)

Answer (score 5):

Each table row needs to have cells, either th (header cells), or td.

In other words, the correct code would be something like I've shown below:

You can use colspan="2" if you'd like the bottom row to span the above two cells as I've done below, or you can use two cells (i.e. Why does this appear on top??.

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
  <tr align="center">
    <td align="left" width="180">
        <a href="http://www.blabllablbalbla.com/"> <img border="0" alt="bablablabla"
        height="" src="/img/logo-beta.png"></img> </a>
    </td>
    <td align="right"><a href="http://support.blablalblbalabl.com">Help Center</a> | <a 
        href="/auth/login">Sign In</a>
    </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
    whyyyyyyyy does this appear on top???!
    </td>  
 </tr>
</table>​​​
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

```
<tr>
    whyyyyyyyy does this appear on top???!
</tr>
```

Because you forgot your `<td>` elements which makes the HTML invalid and render improperly.

Comment: You'll also need to remove that </img> ;)

Answer (score 0):

You're lacking a set of `<td>` tags around the content that's appearing on top:

```
<tr>
    <td>whyyyyyyyy does this appear on top???!</td>
</tr>
```